# global variable stays empty

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of javascript code where I retrieve a list of employees via an ajax-call.

```
var employees_json = '';

Ajax.callbackAsync('getEmployees', ['2627016'],
    function(response){
        employees_json = response;

        console.log('this: '+ employees_json);
    },
    function(error){
        alert('Error while retrieving employees: '+ error);
    }
);

console.log('that: '+ employees_json);
```

(2627016 is the branch_id)

the output on the console:

```
this: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
that:
```

Why is employees_json empty outside the ajax-call?
Or have I made a type I don't see!?!

Comment: Because 'outside' doesn't mean 'after', when dealing with async code.

Comment: Is the order of logs exactly like how you've posted?

Comment: No, I have several console.logs in my code and this is on the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your console.log is executed before the function(response) .

log is not like this ? : 
    that: 
    this: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

javascript is 1 thread , yet you never know when the callback function will run.
so you have to adjust your code .

Comment: I've moved the code that works with the response in the response function.